# Jquery .remove does not delete parent div

Tags: jquery, parent-child, selection

Ok so I have a bunch of thumbnails that when clicked open up modals with more information. I am having trouble figuring out how to delete the modal using jquery.

```
<div class="modal" id="modal">
 <div class="modal-content ">
  <h1>Modal Title</h1>
 <p>help....</p>   
 <button href="#" class="close" id="close" >X</button>
 <div class="modal-content ">
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#close").on("click", function() {
        $( "#modal" ).remove();
    });
</script>
```

Here is a codepen http://codepen.io/Ella33/pen/rrpBOO

Please Help!

Comment: Full disclosure I am a complete noob to jquery...

Comment: Both Sergio and Howzieky answer's below are good and complementary.
See you [upgraded CodePen here](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VKykxG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 8 of your codepen, change `<div class="modal-content ">` to `</div>`. You never closed the div on line 3. I'm assuming you already have jQuery in your actual product, but it not, add it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to load the jQuery library first.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
```

In codepen in the JS section click on the cog where it says add external file place the that line to load jQuery

Answer (score 0):

To close modal using JQuery use the following

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#close").on("click", function() {
        $("#modal").modal('hide');
    });
```

Comment: It wasn't the problem... But I agree that hiding instead of removing can be a good advice... It depends on the context. Still. Your answer is in the woods regarding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery library to your codepen. Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` directly to your html or click on the gear icon in JS section and add external library.
Also, in your html, on line 8 change `<div class="modal-content ">` to `</div>` to close the div with class `modal-content`.